# Display different pages based on form entry

Tags: pages

In addition to 3 public pages, my site has 20 private pages, each of which are built for an individual customer.  I want a user to be able to come to a public page, enter a customer code, and display the appropriate private page for that code.  I don't want to use a dropdown or list because I don't want the other 19 private pages to be visible.  Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: There is more than one route to go with something like this.  Are your private pages fairly static or will the number of them change often? How about customers - do they change daily, yearly or how often would you need to have a new customer setup?

Comment: Hey jdm, thanks for the reply.  The private pages would be fairly static and the customers change once a year.  What do you recommend as the best approach?

Comment: Hey jdm.  I'd still like a way to get to a private page from a public page by entering a code.  Haven't cracked that nut yet.

Comment: The trouble with that is how WordPress checks a user's permission.  This happens inside `get_the_content()` so collecting the password before the page loads (and sending via POST or GET) would be difficult at best.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE.  Based on the additional information you provided, static pages with the list of users changing only once per year, I would recommend simply using the built-in "Password Protected" publishing option.

The Publish metabox (typically in the top right corner of the page editor) has a few options beyond the default public visibility. Simply click "edit" to expand the options.  See screenshot attached.

[image]

Each page published this way can have a unique password that is only shared with the user needing to view the content.

Comment: Thanks, jdm, that sounds like a great solution!  I'll give it a shot.